# Encrypted query in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, encryption

I want to execute a query in our client's server using remove access. If I execute a query something like this `Update abc set col1=12 where id = 2` they will understand what we are doing. So I want some method for encryption and decryption like this:

In our server I encrypt a query like this:

```
encrypt(Update abc set col1=12 where id = 2)
```

So I get output like:

> 0x0100CF465B7B12625EF019E157120D58DD46569AC7BF4118455D12625EF019E157120D58DD46569AC7BF4118455D

And I execute a this encrypted query on client's machine like this:

`decrypt(0x0100CF465B7B12625EF019E157120D58DD46569AC7BF4118455D12625EF019E157120D58DD46569AC7BF4118455D)`

So our client can't understand what we have executed.

Comment: Interesting idea, but what's the question?

Comment: What a bizarre requirement, what level of access does your client have to the database, what level of access do you have?

Comment: If you are running remotely, how will they know what you are doing, if they are running and watching with SQL Profiler, this won't obfuscate anything. It would just make you look shady.

Comment: What's to stop them using the `decrypt` function?

Comment: Why would you want to execute something **in your client's server**, without him knowing what it is? Is that even legal?

Comment: @ypercube Of course it is legal. They are technical persons. If they see our queries, they can capture it and may execute it again themselves. So why should we show them our queries?

Comment: Because you are running them on **their** server? Do you have permissions to do/run whatever you want on this server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a simple decrypt function like this..

```
create proc exec_decrypt(@sql_str varbinary(8000))
as
begin
declare @qry varchar(8000);
select @qry=cast(@sql_str as varchar(8000));
exec(@qry);
end
```

which accepts a varbinary string and converts to varchar and then execute it..

You can generate the encrypted query by using the satament below

```
select CAST('UPDATE users set name =''alex''' as varbinary(8000))
```

then execute the proc exec_decrypt in client place by passing the output of the above query as the parameter for the procedure..

```
Ex:  exec_decrypt 0x55504441544520757365727320736574206E616D65203D27616C657827
```

Hope this will work for you.. Please note that client should not have any permission on the 
proc exec_decrypt

Comment: "Please note that client should not have any permission on the proc exec_decrypt". Not to mention StackOverflow ;-)

Comment: @joe G Joseph The procedure you have shown is fine. But can't we increase the length of varbinary?

Comment: You can use varbinary(MAX) if you need. varbinary(8000) is more than enough for  normal queries

Comment: @JoeGJoseph If I execute the following query:
**select cast((select CAST('select top 1 * from clientmaster where id = 1' as varbinary)) as varchar)**

I get this result **select top 1 * from clientmast** instead of **select top 1 * from clientmaster where id = 1**.

Comment: use varbinary(MAX) instead of just varbinary, Because if we dont specify the length, it will take only 30 characters. I will change my original script now..

Comment: Yes I wanted to do the same!!

Comment: This is obfuscation not encryption. It is quite a well known technique used in SQL injection attacks. e.g. see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2929996/what-is-this-hacker-trying-to-do). Maybe might work if the client is clueless however.

Comment: Also should probably use `nvarchar` to avoid failing if the collation is different.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I have found to ensure that no one can view your queries is to put them in a function or procedure using 'with encryption'. Run the below code to see for yourself. Dynamic SQL suggested in the earlier answer doesn't fully solve your problem.

```
create procedure dbo.dummy_drop_me with encryption as select t.* from sys.dm_exec_requests r cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (r.sql_handle) t where r.session_id = @@spid
go
exec dbo.dummy_drop_me
go
select t.* from sys.dm_exec_requests r cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (r.sql_handle) t where r.session_id = @@spid
go
exec ('select t.* from sys.dm_exec_requests r cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text (r.sql_handle) t where r.session_id = @@spid')
```

The only way I have found to keep someone from capturing your functions and procedures is to create them in their own database on a server where no one has access. Then, attach a copy of the database to the servers where you need them.

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, **With Encryption** is generally counter-productive as there are a number of Sql Server decryption tools. ie dbForge's DB Decryptor. I just used this to decrypt a database's T-SQL, so I could export DACPAC's and BACPAC's for use in Azure DevOps automated deployments. **With Encryption** causes DACPAC and BACPAC exports to fail. This means, if you implement **With Encryption** you cannot use DACPAC to create update scripts for DB Patches or direct updates, you cannot use Visual Studio Sql Server Tools projects, which makes DB development harder. You have not secured anything, just made it harder for Dev's and Op's to do their jobs.